# Can we resolve this equation for $ABx = (\mathcal 1 ABx)^{-1}ABx$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have two diagonal matrices $A$ and $B$ and $\mathbf1$ denotes the vector consisting of $1$ with the respective dimension. Is it possible to solve the following system?

$$ABx = (\mathbf 1^\top ABx)^{-1}ABx$$

On top we have the condition that $\sum_iA_{ii}=1$. I don't think, but I can't find a formal argument. How can I go about this?

Comment: How do you ensure that $1^T ABx \neq 0$?

Comment: I don't quite understand what $\mathbf 1$ means. Is it the vector with coordinates $(1,1,...)$ where $1$ is the identity of the underlying field?

Comment: @Nothingspecial, yes indeed that is the vector $(1,1,\dots,1)$

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace you can assume that is satisfied for all $x\neq0$

Comment: No you cannot, this is false for any $x \in B^T A^T 1^\bot$

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the diagonal elements of $A,B$ be $a_i, b_i$ respectively. Then the equation boils down to
$$
a_ib_ix_i = {a_ib_ix_i\over \sum_i a_ib_ix_i}
$$
The denominator of the right hand side is a scalar. Assume it is nonzero. Then for this equation to hold, the denominator must be 1. Now you have this constraint
$$
\sum_i a_ib_ix_i = 1
$$
which reduces the degree of freedom of $x$ by one, but otherwise as Lucas stated in his answer, the solution is on a hyperplane.

Meanwhile, the condition $\sum_i a_i = 1$ you added doesn't change the degree of freedom of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $C=AB \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{F})$, so $(1^TCx)Cx = Cx \implies C^{-1} (1^TCx)Cx = x$.

Then, $$C^{-1} ( \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n c_{ij} x_j ) Cx = x $$

So, $ ( \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n c_{ij}  x_j) x = x $.

Maybe look at this equation?

First guess would be to look at $\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n c_{ij}  x_j =1$.

So you have an equation of the form $\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_jx_j = 1$. This represents an affine hyperplane. So, infinitely many solutions right?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).